# Increased memory consumed by matplotlib when plotting in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory-management

I am using matplotlib as part of a Python application to analyze some data. 
My goal is to loop over a container of objects and, for each of those, produce a plot of the contained data. Here it is a list of the used versions:

- Python 3.6.9
- matplotlib 3.1.1
- numpy 1.15.4

**PROBLEM**

The problem I am experiencing is that the memory consumed by the Python application grows significantly during the loop that generates the graphs, to a point where the computer becomes almost unresponsive.

I have simplified the implementation into simple code that can be run to reproduce the behavior (this was inspired by a post I found on [matplotlib github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8519) while searching for some answers on the web)

```
import logging
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from memory_profiler import profile
from memory_profiler import memory_usage
import numpy as np

TIMES = 20
SAMPLES_PER_LINE = 20000
STATIONS = 100
np_ax = np.linspace(1, STATIONS, num=SAMPLES_PER_LINE)
np_ay = np.random.random_sample(size=SAMPLES_PER_LINE)

logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")

@profile
def do_plots_close(i):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10), dpi=60)
    for stn in range(STATIONS):
        plt.plot(np_ax, np_ay + stn)

    s_file_name = 'withClose_{:03d}.png'.format(i)
    plt.savefig(s_file_name)
    logging.info("Printed file %s", s_file_name)
    plt.close(fig)


@profile
def do_plots_clf(i):
    plt.clf()
    for stn in range(STATIONS):
        plt.plot(np_ax, np_ay + stn)

    s_file_name = "withCLF_{:03d}.png".format(i)
    plt.savefig(s_file_name)
    logging.info("Printed file %s", s_file_name)


def with_close():
    for i in range(TIMES):
        do_plots_close(i)


def with_clf():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10), dpi=60)
    for i in range(TIMES):
        do_plots_clf(i)
    plt.close(fig)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info("Matplotlib backend used: %s", mpl.get_backend())
    mem_with_close = memory_usage((with_close, [], {}))
    mem_with_clf = memory_usage((with_clf, [], {}))
    plt.plot(mem_with_close, label='New figure opened and closed at each loop')
    plt.plot(mem_with_clf, label='Single figure cleared at every loop')

    plt.legend()
    plt.title("Backend: {:s} - memory usage".format(mpl.get_backend()))
    plt.ylabel('MB')
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel('time [s * 0.1]')  # `memory_usage` logs every 100ms
    plt.show()
```

There are 2 functions that plot `TIMES` graphs each with `SAMPLES` lines with `SAMPLES_PER_LINE` elements (somewhat close to the size of the data I am dealing with). `do_plots_close()` creates a new figure at the beginning of each loop and closes it at the end; whereas `do_plots_clf()` operates on the same figure after that a cleanup is performed.
`memory_profiler` is used to get the memory consumed by the 2 functions, which is then plotted into a figure that is attached:

[image: Pattern of the memory consumed by <code>with_close()</code> and <code>with_clf()</code>]

Looking at the figure, it is clear that in neither of the functions the memory consumed by a single figure is completely freed after the figure is closed (for `do_plots_close()`) or cleared (for `do_plots_clf()`). **I have also tried to remove the `figsize` option when the figure is created, but I did not see any difference in the outcome**.

**QUESTION**

I am looking for a better way to handle this problem and reduce the amount of memory that is used in the function saving the graphs.

- Am I misusing the matplotlib API?
- Is there a way to manage the same amount of data without suffering this memory increase?
- Why the memory seems to be released only after several plots are done?

Any help and suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Garbage collection only happens periodically.  You can force it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use the [garbage collector](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html):

- **Why the memory seems to be released only after several plots are done?**

  - garbage collection is periodic, unless forced.
- Performed with PyCharm

#### Initial plot, with no garbage collection:

- While I'm not using the Qt5 backend, the initial plots are comparable.

  - Therefore, I assume the plots generated with garbage collection will also be comparable, for this example.

[image]

#### Add `gc.collect()` to `def do_plots_close(i)`:

```py
import gc

def do_plots_close(i):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10), dpi=60)
    for stn in range(STATIONS):
        plt.plot(np_ax, np_ay + stn)

    s_file_name = 'withClose_{:03d}.png'.format(i)
    plt.savefig(s_file_name)
    logging.info("Printed file %s", s_file_name)
    plt.close(fig)
    gc.collect()
```

[image: with garbage collection]

#### Also add `gc.collect` to `def with_clf()`:

```py
def with_clf():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10), dpi=60)
    for i in range(TIMES):
        do_plots_clf(i)
        gc.collect()
    plt.close(fig)
```

[image]

### With Jupyter Lab and ipykernel:

- ipykernel doesn't release memory when figures are opened and closed, even with garbage collection
- ipykernel seems to allocate memory to the figure for `def with_clf`, responding marginally to `clf` and garbage collection

#### No garbage collection

[image]

#### With garbage collection

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Trenton for the answer and the additional analysis.
Forcing the garbage collection surely improves the situation dramatically.
The overall performances (specially the execution time) does not seem to be affected by the garbage collector.

So, overall this solution seems to improve things and works for me (so far).
Cheers!